# Gradiente del MSE

Tags: machine-learning, inteligencia-artificial, redes-neuronales

Debo calcular el gradiente del MSE respecto a la entrada (evaluado en el P_est).
Tengo la siguiente función:

```
MSE_grad_out = MSE_grad(P_true, P_est)
```

Por otro lado tengo :

```
def NotImplemented_message():
    return np.array([1, 1]

def MSE_grad(X_true, X_pred):
    return NotImplemented_message()
```

Tengo el P_true y el P_est como dato,  pero no logro entender como armar la función para que me de el resultado. Que debería modificar en las funciones para obtener un resultado.?

Saludos

Comment: Hola Andres! No se entiende la pregunta. El `MSE` o `Mean Square Error` (Error Cuadrático Medio), se calcula con respecto a la salida, no la entrada. Por otro lado no estás haciendo el calculo del '`MSE` porque la función encargada de calcularlo no lo ha implementado. Simplemente no calcula el `mse` si no que devuelve un array `[1,1]`

Comment: Hola Alberto . Gracias por la respuesta. Es asi como esta escrito lo cual me genera confusión. Igualmente la pregunta es como puedo hacerlo con lapiz y papel a los cálculos .Por ejemplo me piden Cuanto vale el gradiente del MSE respecto a la entrada (evaluado en el P_est)? Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con calculo?